# Data encryption at REST on aws EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption

I have 2 specific questions about [Amazon EBS Encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-ebs.html#ebs-encrypt).

1. What is the benefit of using encrypted EBS?
2. If create encrypted EBS and attached to the instance, will i able to read the data if i login using ssh?

Appreciate if you could explain in brief.

Thanks and Regards,

Vady

Comment: Note that the data in transit between your instance and your EBS volume travels over a network (EBS is network-attached). If you use EBS Encryption then that data is encrypted/decrypted on the physical machine hosting your EC2 instance so all data in transit to/from the EBS volume is encrypted. Also, note that the encryption at rest extends to snapshots of EBS volumes. All important for regulatory compliance.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

1. AWS employees with direct access to the underlying hardware cannot view your data. That's really the only advantage. You might have to do this for meeting security compliance requirements such as PCI or HIPAA. If not, there isn't much reason to enable EBS encryption.
2. The data appears to the server as if it is unencrypted. Otherwise it would be unusable and there would be no point of offering this feature.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hypothetically, what if AWS employees spin up an EC2 and attach the EBS volume in underlying hardware?